# MVC - Dynamic Routing potential security problem?

Tags: php

Is dynamic routing as described on https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-2/ a potential security problem?

Implementation

```
<?php
$model = $_GET['model'];
$view = $_GET['view'];
$controller = $_GET['controller'];
$action = $_GET['action'];

if (!(empty($model) || empty($view) || empty($controller) || empty($action))) {
    $m = new $model();
    $c = new $controller($m, $action);
    $v = new $view($m);
    echo $v->output();
}
```

I wonder if you could do something potentially harmful by just creating objects from user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a vulnerability. OWASP calls it [Unsafe use of Reflection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection), and as they state:

> in larger applications where complexity grows exponentially it is not
>   unreasonable that an attacker could find a constructor to leverage as
>   part of an attack